# Tomcat HTTP status 404 Not found error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, http-status-code-404

When I deploy my war file in Tomcat 7, I get the 404 error page. I can able to run my application in jetty server from within eclipse with no problems. I'm just doing a war export and deploying the application in Tomcat 7 `webapps` folder and starting the tomcat server with port `9090` and it returns 404 not found error. Tomcat server starts successfully and so does my application. I see no errors in the log files. My application gets deployed normally. I've also tried adding a welcome file list but it isn't working.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
     version="2.5">

<display-name>mywebapp - Maven Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mywebappServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/config/springContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mywebappServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

My controller class listens for "/" , "/login" and "/index" requests and maps to the login and index pages accordingly.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)

@RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

The above mappings works fine in jetty server. After starting tomcat, I can see in the Webapp Manager page that my app started and running is set to true. When I click on the mywebapp then it show me 404 error.

Note: The war file name and the url I'm accessing are both same. The URL I'm accessing my webapp is `http://localhost:9090/mywebapp` and the war file name is `mywebapp.war`.

Here's my tomcat logs,

```
2016-02-05 15:37:13 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9090"]
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 699 ms
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.50
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\mywebapp.war
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:25 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [178] milliseconds.
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\host-manager
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\manager
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9090"]
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 05, 2016 3:37:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 12010 ms
```

and while I try to access the `http://localhost:9090/mywebapp` url I get the following in the tomcat-stdout-xx as output,

```
WARN [http-bio-9090-exec-5] servlet.DispatcherServlet (DispatcherServlet.java:1136) - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mywebapp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mywebappServlet'
```

What could be wrong in my configuration?

Comment: You are using relative paths for your spring xml config files in web.xml for contextConfigLocation. Looks like they did not match with the Tomcat classpath, so they are not picked up. Have you checked, that your beans are really initialized after tomcat start?

Comment: Asking for @paweln1986: Seems like spring MVC was not started. Could you attach also your springContext.xml ?

Comment: @RainerMontag and paweln1986 My springContext.xml and applicationContext.xml has no problems loading. When I start tomcat using tomcat7.exe in command prompt interface. I can see the servlet context file loading messages. So I don't think loading bean definitions are the problem here. I can also see this message in logs `Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springContext.xml]`. So doesn't seems to be the issue.